# What's wrong with this input?

Tags: java

[image]

Why it's showing error, when I enter just 5 digit number in long data type?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: but without the image you wouldn't have seen Comic Sans as a coding font :-)

Comment: In the future, include code in a question as pasted text, not as an image of text.  We can’t copy an image into our editors, we can’t search for text in an image, images are often scaled in browsers in ways that make them difficult to read, and sight impaired users won’t be able to do anything with them.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers starting with 0 are interpreted as octal numbers in Java, that are 8-based numbers. A 9 or 8 cannot appear in octal number, thus the warning.

Comment: I am new to Stack overflow! If you don't mind, can I know(If you have any Idea) why my question got many downvotes?

Comment: @user14549997 The first comment on your question has a link that explains it.